# Issue With ViewController I am using PageMenu Third party library

Tags: uiview, viewcontroller

When Controller present it shows white space. When I am clicking another tab and comeback to the same tab. which shown white space. Then working fine . let me know how can I remove white space in it.(White space is showing above of Buy MB for BTC)

Screenshot :

[image: Click for Screenshot]

```
 override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    pager()
}

func pager()
{
    let buy = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "BuyMBVCSID") as! BuyMBVC
    buy.parentNavigationController = navigationController!
    buy.title = "Buy MB"
    controllerArray.append(buy)

    let sell = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SellMBVCSID") as! SellMBVC
    sell.parentNavigationController = navigationController!
    sell.title = "Sell MB"
    controllerArray.append(sell)



    // Customize menu (Optional)
    let parameters: [CAPSPageMenuOption] = [
        .scrollMenuBackgroundColor(UIColor(red: 72/255.0, green: 175/255.0, blue: 230/255.0, alpha: 1.0)),
        .viewBackgroundColor(UIColor(red: 255.0/255.0, green: 255.0/255.0, blue: 255.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)),

        .selectionIndicatorColor(UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 255/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1.0)),
        .addBottomMenuHairline(false),
        .menuItemFont(UIFont(name: "Times New Roman", size: 16)!),
        .menuItemWidth((self.pagerView.frame.width-30)/3),
        .menuHeight(50.0),
        .enableHorizontalBounce(true),
        .menuItemWidthBasedOnTitleTextWidth(false),
        .selectedMenuItemLabelColor(UIColor.white),

        .unselectedMenuItemLabelColor(UIColor.white),
        .menuItemSeparatorWidth(4.5),
        .useMenuLikeSegmentedControl(false),
        .menuItemSeparatorRoundEdges(true),
        .selectionIndicatorHeight(2.0),
        .menuItemSeparatorPercentageHeight(0.0),
        ]

    // Initialize scroll menu
    pageMenu = CAPSPageMenu(viewControllers: controllerArray, frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: self.pagerView.frame.width, height: self.pagerView.frame.height), pageMenuOptions: parameters)

    self.pagerView.addSubview(pageMenu!.view)

    // End Pagemenu
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

`.selectionIndicatorColor(UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 255/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1.0))`

to

`.selectionIndidcatorColor(UIColor.clear)`

that should do the trick

Comment: ok, try change  .selectionIndicatorHeight(2.0) to .selectionIndicatorHeight(0)